# How to update textview of fragment "continuously" from viewpageradpater?viewpager adapter is in main fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My viewpager adapter is in another fragment(i.e. in main fragment) i.e. i used viewpager in another fragment.so viewpager adapter having 2 fragments.

I am getting heart rate value continuously from main fragment and need to send it to viewpager adapter.then viewpager adapter send this value to fragment and upadate the textview here.

//Main Fragment were i initialize fragmentpageradapter with updated heart rate value:-`((readingdata)samplePagerAdapter).passdata(value);`

used interface to update value:-

```
    public interface readingdata
{
    void passdata(int value);
}
```

//Adapter code:-

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements readingdata {

private final Random random = new Random();
private int mSize = 2;
private int heart_rate;
FragmentManager fm;
private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;

public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, int heart) {
    super(supportFragmentManager);
    fm = supportFragmentManager;
    mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mSize;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


    Fragment f = null;

    if (position == 0) {
        f = new MyFragment().newInstance(heart_rate);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        f = new SecondFragment();
    }

    return f;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    if (object instanceof Fragment) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        String tag = fragment.getTag();
        mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
    }
    return object;
}



public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
    if (tag != null) {
        fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void passdata(int value) {

    heart_rate=value;
}
```

}

//Fragment code were textview updated on regular interval

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

private int heart_rate;
private ArcProgress arc_progress;
private TextView tv_heartrate;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveBundle) {


    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ecg_layout, container, false);

    handler=new Handler();
    arc_progress = (ArcProgress) view.findViewById(R.id.arc_progress);
    tv_heartrate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_heart_rate);

    handler=new Handler();

    handler.post(runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            MyFragment myFragment=new MyFragment();
            arc_progress.setProgress(heart_rate);
            tv_heartrate.setText(String.valueOf(heart_rate));

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}


public static Fragment newInstance(int heartvalue) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    f.heart_rate = heartvalue;
    return f;
}
```

}

So how should i update textview continuously inside the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In MainFragment**

```
private static HeartRateListener heartRateListener;
        public static void setHeartRateListener(HeartRateListener listener){
            heartRateListener = listener;
        }
public static interface HeartRateListener{
            void onHeartRate(int yourValue);
}

    // Send your continuously updated value
        heartRateListener.onHeartRate(yourValue);
```

**In ViewPager Fragment** (inside onViewCreated())

```
MainFragment.setHeartRateListener(new MainFragment.HeartRateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHeartRate(int yourValue) {
               // Update your textview with yourValue
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   create Method 

          public void updateScreenData(String text)
 {
                    tv_heartrate.setText(text);
   } 

   in fragment and then call this method from activity
    make sure that fragment reference is not null whenever call this method
```

Comment: I am already done with this one but it gets null pointer exception on tv_heartrate because textview initialize on fragment's oncreateview().

Answer (score 0):

```
   Take Help from this and save reference to view you are inflating 

    package com.mtg.workapp_v2.listing.wanted.add_wanted;

    import android.content.Context;
   import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.mtg.classes.AddressView;
   import com.mtg.classes.ListingVisibilityLayout;
  import com.mtg.utils.CommonMethods;
   import com.mtg.workapp.R;


     public class WantedBasicInfoFragment extends Fragment implements           View.OnClickListener{

  private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
   private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

  View FragmentView ;
  Context myContext;

   TextView text_continue;
   EditText edit_title;
   EditText edit_description;

   private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

//this is add by ahsan according to new design
  ListingVisibilityLayout listingVisibilityLayout = null;


  public WantedBasicInfoFragment() {
  }


  public static WantedBasicInfoFragment newInstance(String param1, String   param2) {
      WantedBasicInfoFragment fragment = new WantedBasicInfoFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
      args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
     fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
   }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FragmentView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wanted_basic, container, false);
    init();
    return FragmentView;
}

/********************************************************************************/

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);

}

/********************************************************************************/

public void setListener(OnFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

/********************************************************************************/

public void setInitValues()
{


}

/***********************************************************************************/

public void updateScreenData()
{


    edit_title.setText(wantedInformation.csName);
    edit_description.setText(wantedInformation.csDescription);



}

/***********************************************************************************/

public void init()
{
    myContext=getActivity();


    text_continue=(TextView) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.text_continue);

    edit_title = (EditText) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.edit_title);

    edit_description = (EditText) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.edit_description);

    text_continue.setOnClickListener(this);

    edit_title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            wantedInformation.csListingLanguage = CommonMethods.getInputLanguage(myContext);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            wantedInformation.csListingLanguage = CommonMethods.getInputLanguage(myContext);
        }
    });

    initVisibilitySpinner();

}

/***********************************************************************************/

public void initVisibilitySpinner()
{
    listingVisibilityLayout = new ListingVisibilityLayout(myContext);
    View visibilityView = (View)FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.id_visibility_layout);
    listingVisibilityLayout.ListingVisibilityInit(visibilityView);

}

/***********************************************************************************/
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int itemID = view.getId();

    switch (itemID) {
        case R.id.text_continue:
        {
            moveToNextScreen(true);
        }

    }
}


/***********************************************************************************/

public void moveToNextScreen(boolean isContinueClicked)
{
    String csName = edit_title.getText().toString().trim();
    String csDescription = edit_description.getText().toString().trim();

    if(csName.length() <= 0 && csDescription.toString().length() <= 0)
    {
        CommonMethods.showMessageBox("",     getResources().getString(R.string.id_please_enter_name_and_description), myContext);
        return;
    }
    else if(csName.length() <= 0)
    {
        CommonMethods.showMessageBox("", getResources().getString(R.string.id_please_enter_name), myContext);
        return;
    }
    else if(csDescription.length() <= 0)
    {
        CommonMethods.showMessageBox("", getResources().getString(R.string.id_please_enter_description), myContext);
        return;
    }
    else  if(listingVisibilityLayout.selectedProfileVisibility.csOptionID.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))
    {
        CommonMethods.showMessageBox("", getResources().getString(R.string.id_select_visibility_option_msg), myContext);
        return;
    }


    wantedInformation.csName = csName;
    wantedInformation.csDescription = csDescription;

    wantedInformation.visibilityOption = listingVisibilityLayout.selectedProfileVisibility;

    //MH: If continue clicked then continue Button listener will be called
    //MH: If only tick is clicked in Edit Mode then onUpdate listener will be called
    //MH: and data will be updated before sent to api
    //MH: The below statements are repeated in all fragments of Wanted
    if(isContinueClicked)
    mListener.continueButtonPressed(wantedInformation);
    else
        mListener.onUpdate(wantedInformation);
}
```

}

Comment: also in activity  Save Reference to Fragment as well after it is initailized